# Machine Check Exception reported by kernel

Tags: cpu, kernel-panic, machine-check-exception

I built a new computer:

- Intel Core i7 4770K
- Gigabyte Z87N-WIFI
- Samsung 840 Evo S x2 (in RAID 0)
- 450w Corsair RM 80Plus
- Dark Rock Pro 3 Cooling
- Kingston 1600 DDR3
- NO DEDICATED GPU

Operating System:

- Linux Mint 16 Petra

The BIOS settings are completely default, except from the RAID configuration. The CPU is NOT overclocked, nor ever has been since I bought it.

About 3 times per day since I built the system it will unexpectedly crash and go to a black screen saying "Machine Check Exception ...", image below:

[image]

The temperature looks good:

```
➜  ~  sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +41.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +41.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C
```

Updated BIOS to latest.

Can somebody tell me what the problem could be?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Was the CPU working before? Have you checked for bent pins on the motherboard? Have you tried distros other than Mint 16?

Comment: Have tried with a number of Linux distros: Fedora, Ubuntu, and Linux Mint with PCRE. All of them crash similarly. Is it likely to be a faulty motherboard or faulty CPU causing this error?

Comment: It might be a CPU failure. Try downloading [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/index.php) (don't bother registering) and run the Blend test (`mprime -m` to run the config utilty) for 6-8 hours (3 minimum). It'll keep running till you stop it or it encounters an error.

Comment: ACPI temperatures are no good. My server also reports these exact temperatures—at any given time. Try using `lm_sensors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a hardware problem. `mcelog --ascii` reports the following:

```
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
CPU 0 BANK 4 TSC 2d95278285f8
RIP !INEXACT! 10:ffffffff816f6570
MISC 0
TIME 1398091195 Mon Apr 21 16:39:55 2014
MCG status:RIPV MCIP
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
MCi_MISC register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal unclassified error: 402
STATUS ba00000052000402 MCGSTATUS 5
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 60
SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 9
```

...which is unfortunately not very helpful. It’s probably some undocumented internal CPU error. Your best bet would be to go for a warranty exchange (of your CPU), if possible.

Comment: You were right, it was a faulty CPU.